# xcode doesn't show 'arc4random_uniform '

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

I am using xcode 7.2. I want to generate random integer, in xcode, when I type `arc4random`, it however doesn't suggest `arc4random_uniform` , why?

Here is the screenshots of what xcode suggested, you see, no `arc4random_uniform` :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

please update your `Xcode` to last version.

It seems like functions that use u_int32_t are just not parsed correctly by Swift. It is precisely those that are absent from the generated Swift declarations. You can also see that it is has seen the declaration by looking at the line in stdlib.h:

```
u_int32_t arc4random_uniform(u_int32_t /*upper_bound*/) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_4_3);
```

which is rendered as:

```
/*upper_bound*/
```

in Xcode. The comment is preserved, but the declaration is ignored. The stdlib.h file itself is identical to the one in beta 5. It is almost identical to the one in Xcode 6.3.2, only the "system" function is changed to be prohibited on WatchOS.